# What do I write for Försäkringskassans "address in Sweden" question after leaving the country, considering I don't have one?

Tags: sweden, bureaucracy

I have recently left Sweden after having lived there as a Dutch national for six years.  I informed Swedish *Skatteverket*, who administrate residencies.  Then, *Försäkringskassan* sent me a form asking me some details about my foreign residency ([FK5459](https://www.forsakringskassan.se/wps/wcm/connect/0e181cce-55a9-4398-8c63-f5790aff4656/FK5459_015_F_003Uppgifter+Flyttning+till+eller+arbete+i+ett+annat+land.pdf?MOD=AJPERES)), such as my current address, employers' address, etc.  They also ask for an address in Sweden: *Utdelningsadress i Sverige*.  Not having any address in Sweden, can I leave this blank or must I have some contact in Sweden indefinately?  Or do I write my most recent Swedish address?

Comment: A reference of some kind to the actual form would probably be useful.

Comment: @unwind Good point.  I added a link to the form (which is in Swedish).

Comment: The form you refer to is for people who will move away. If you've already left, it seems like you'd want to use a different form, such as 5069, which is also available in other languages.

Comment: @gerrit I added in the ID of the form, please correct me if it's not the right one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TLDR;** Your most recent Swedish address.

I sent an email to Försäkringskassan regarding the address in Sweden on form FK5459, and this was their response:

> Utdelningsadress i Sverige är din senaste (folkbokförings-)adress i Sverige.
>   /.../
>   Din nationalitet spelar ingen roll.

My translation:

> Your Swedish Utdelningsaddress is your most recent (registered) address in Sweden. /.../ Your nationality does not matter.

In my translation above, registered means registered at Skatteverket. So you should write your most recent Swedish address in the field for *Utdelningsadress i Sverige*.